# How does one compute this double integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_0^2\int_0^{y^3} x^5(2-x^{1/3})^{-1} \, dx \, dy$$

I've tried change of variables, which didn't seem to help much. I've also tried u-substitution and that didn't help. What I noticed is that there is $x=y^3$ so $y=x^{1/3}$, but I wasn't sure how to use that fact besides change of variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the easiest thing? Change the order of integration.

So, let's see:

\begin{align*}
\int_0^8\int_{x^{1/3}}^2 x^5(2-x^{1/3})^{-1}\,dy\,dx &= \int_0^8 (2-x^{1/3}) x^5(2-x^{1/3})^{-1}\,dx \\ &= \int_0^2 x^5\,dx.\end{align*}
Can you finish now?

Comment: I did, but it still made me stuck

Comment: @ebehr Maybe double-check what region over which you are integrating

Comment: That makes sense. When I did change of variables for some reason I did y from 0 to x^1/3. Wow, that is foolish of me.

Comment: Yeah, it's important to sketch the region carefully. When I did this at the keyboard, I inadvertently and sloppily got it wrong at first.

Comment: Same here! Sometimes it really does help to draw the region.  For me, the sketch lets me be more certain that I have the boundaries correct after changing the order of integration, and faster than symbolically analyzing the boundary info ("symbolically" as in setting up systems of inequalities without doing any sketching).

Comment: @ZxJx and ebehr: If you're interested in a few more challenging 3D changes of order of integration, see parts of 3510 lectures 5 and 6 [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd). You might a few other lectures of interest, too.